# Rewritten URL should contain #. How can I resolve this?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Actually I want to rewrite URL through `.htaccess`.

My actual URL is

```
front/property/uploadphotos_pid.php?pid=11#NO
```

I want to convert this to

```
uploadphotos_pid/11/NO.php
```

and have written following code:

```
RewriteRule ^uploadphotos_pid/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+).php$ 
front/property/uploadphotos_pid.php?pid=$1&#=$2
```

Comment: So for the general understanding. You receive this URL from the client, the url cannot be changed, because you cannot change the target script?

Answer (score 4):

The fragment identifier (the section of a URI starting with `#`) is handled entirely client side. It is not sent to the server. The server (which is where mod_rewrite runs) therefore cannot do anything with it.

Comment: it meands i can not rewrite this url if url contains any inner links for this code

Comment: You can rewrite the URL — but only the portion of it that appears before the `#`

Comment: You could use some js & php code to copy the behaviour. Send the target anchor to the php script as a parameter. Then add some js code to the resulting page which jumps to the anchor in an onload event in jquery this could look like `$('document').ready(function() { window.location.href = anchor; });`

Comment: please define brief because i set this url on the .htaccess file and its contains the correct url we can not escape the # from ur other wise it will be error........

Comment: So brief define plese help me

Answer (score 0):

# must be [escaped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as %23 in a URL

Comment: but we pass a inner links # with my url

Comment: but we pass a inner links # with my url so it takes problems but how i resolved it properly please tell me

Comment: @user725013 sorry, missunderstood your question